# Wait for request to be sent, but not response with Javascript promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I need to send some data to the server to change the active 'obligation' that is being served up.

I need to wait for the active obligation to change before I do anything with the website.

However, I don't need the response that fetch gets me. I would like to wait until the data is sent, but not have to wait until I receive the response.

```
async function scrape(obligations) {
    array = []
    for (obligation in obligations) {
        data = await switchObligations(obligations[obligation]).then(async function() {
        let obj = {}
            const promises = config.filter(function(page){
                if (page.active === true && page.name !== 'debtorAddress') {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }).map(async (page) => {
                    let data;
                    htmlText = await getPage(page)

                    if(page.type !== 'table') {data = await parsePage(page, htmlText);}
                    else {let table = getTable(htmlText, undefined, page)
                    }
                    return data;        
        })
        data = Promise.all(promises).then(dataArray => {
            let data = Object.assign({}, ...dataArray)
            array.push(data);
            return array;
        })
        return await data
        }); 

    }
    return await data
} 

async function switchObligations(obligation){
    //Changes the active obligation
    const res = fetch("https://djr.view.civicacloud.com.au/Traffic/Notices/forms/NoticesManagement/SearchNotice.aspx?&NoticeNo=" + obligation, {
      method: 'GET',
  });
  return res
}
```

[image]

Comment: `fetch` is not the right thing to use in that case - since the promise returned by `fetch` resolves to the `Response` to the request - even if using XMLHttpRequest then when `readyState == 2` is probably too late for you (headers received) if I'm reading the question correctly (the image does not help at all, as it's pointing to two separate requests, rather than "phases" within requests)

Comment: I think you are reading the question correctly. The noticedetails.aspx is part of the response since it's a redirect. I would like the program to continue once SeachNotice is finished. I have selected two obligations, so everything is repeated twice.

Comment: no, a different image wont help because I don't know what you want - and after thinking further, the fetch promise resolves when the response headers are received, not necessarily the response body ... when you think about it, there's no way to tell "when the data is sent", except to wait for the response headers ... and seeing as your code does nothing with the response, it's not waiting for the response to finish coming down

Comment: perhaps if you showed more code ... i.e. how the SearchNotice, noticeDetails and noticeKeeper requests are being made with respect to each other

Comment: Ok I have added more code. NoticeKeeper is called in the parsePage function, but all the waiting happens in `scrape()`.

Comment: and notice details? is that done in `getPage` - because as your code stands, `parsePage` wont be called until whatever promise `getPage` returns is fullfilled

Comment: I get NoticeDetails because when I send the get request with a new obligation number to SearchNotice, search notice responds with a 302 redirect. It's not something that I need.

Comment: OK, so, at the moment `noticeKeeper` isn't fetched until `NoticeDetails` finishes, but you want `noticeKeeper` to be fetches as soon as `SearchNotice` finishes? i.e. at the same time that `NoticeDetails` begins?

Comment: Exactly. You are correct.

Comment: oh, wait, `searchNotice` redirects to `NoticeDetails` and you don't want to wait for the redirect? so what is `getPage` waiting for?

Comment: Yes. I want to start fetching noticeKeeper a the same time NoticeDetails would be sent.

Comment: try `fetch("https://....", {method:"GET", redirect:"manual"})` --- see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters)

Comment: Yep that worked perfectly. What an easy fix.

Comment: You realise the "follow" URL won't even be accessed now - is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much discussion in the comments, the requirement was to not follow the redirect response returned from the URL in the `switchObligations` function

This is achieved by using the `redirect:` property of the `init` argument to `fetch`

i.e., in the code

```
fetch("https://***url***", {
    method: 'GET',
})
```

add redirect: property as follows

```
fetch("https://***url***", {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'manual'
})
```

Comment: What's the difference between `follow: 'manual'` and `redirect: 'manual'`?

Comment: sorry, typo on my part - I was thinking of the possible values for redirect, the default being `'follow'` :p